# Verb *be* followed by nominative or accusative case of the pronoun

Tags: sentence-structure, pronouns, relative-pronouns, subjects, definition

**It is I who need your help.
It is me that needs your help.**

*Source Practical English Usage*

In the first example, the verb *be* is followed by a nominative case of the personal pronoun and the relative pronoun is *who* that's functioning as a subject but taking *need* as a verb which agrees to *I*.
In the second example the verb *be* is followed by accusative case *me* and the relative pronoun is *that* that's functioning as subject and taking singular verb *needs* that agrees to relative pronoun*that*.

Both examples have the verb *be* but different cases of the same pronoun and there is also different usage of relative pronouns. Why does the verb *need* to change its property?

Comment: What examples?? Is that explanation in your first paragraph in the book?

Comment: In this cleft relative _It is I who need your help_ has simple agreement. It follows the general rules for relative clauses, with the relative pronoun "who" being construed as 1st person singular by virtue of its anaphoric relationship to "I". But in the less formal _It is me that needs your help_ the antecedent is in accusative case, and here the 1st person property is not carried over to "that", so the latter takes on the default 3rd person feature, i.e. it has 3rd person override.

Comment: Incidentally, the switch from "who" to "that" is not relevant. There's no requirement in your second example for "who" to be replaced with "that". It would be perfectly fine to say _It is me who needs your help_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both sentences are pretty bad; they seem only to exist to create a grammatical problem

As an English learner you should first realise that the correct way to say this is "I need your help".

As nouns don't have case in English, we only have the vestiges of a case system in the pronouns.  English allows for either the nominative or accusative case when pronouns are the complement in a sentence.  Generally, using the nominative case is formal (nominative case is required by Latin, so this is an "educated" style)

I don't see much difference between the "who" and "that" relative clauses.  Since "I" am a person, the "educated" style would be to use "who",  so "It is I who..." seems to be consistent in style. The formal use of "I" requires a first person agreement in the verb. This makes this example super-formal.

Less formal use of "me" is consistent with "that".  The first person agreement is only with first person subject "I". As there is no first person subject pronoun to agree with, the "default" is for the relative pronoun to be treated as third person.

It would not be wrong to say

> It is I that need your help.

nor

> It is me who needs your help.

So how do native speakers solve this problem?  They cut the Gordian knot by saying "*I* need your help". This expresses the same idea.

It is very hard to judge what is natural in a deliberately unnatural sentence. I don't think there is much to be learned about English from analysing this example.

Comment: Surely "It is I who..." has the additional meaning "I and not someone else"?

Comment: I'd say it's a matter of style level. with "I" being formal and taking simple 1st person agreement, while less formal "me" takes 3rd person "needs", i.e. it has 3rd person override.

Comment: Just to clarify my last comment concerning the use of the term 'override: Since the antecedent in the second example is accusative "me", its 1st person property is not carried over to the relative clause, as it is in the first example with nominal "I", and thus the covert relative pronoun "who" takes on its default value of 3rd person. Hence 3rd person "needs".

Comment: Actually, I don't think the informal equivalent of this sentence is usually  "I need your help" (with stress on "I"), but rather "I'm the one who needs your help."